# Android Studio - Build variation & Module selection

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an application which needs a library with 2 variants - simulator & actual.

My objective is to create build tasks say assembleSimulatorDebug & assembleDebug.
assembleSimulatorDebug will include simulator module/library and assembleDebug will include actual module to build the apk.

I'm thinking of having if else blocks in dependencies sections of build.gradle. Can I have something like this?

I'm very new to gradle and trying from yesterday to set up something like this. It will be v helpful if anyone can provide some hints or links where I can get an idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
Found another solution. It's in another my answer.

It is possible by usage of 'Flavor products' of android gradle plugin. You can split library implementation by product flavor.

Initial requirements *'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'*, *Android Studio 1.0.1*.

I created [project at GitHub](https://github.com/igozhenko/gradle-27519128), so you'll be able to get it, run and learn.

You need to create two flavors of your app and library, too. For example,  `normal` and `simulator`

Application's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tivogi.gradle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        normal {
        }
        simulator {
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    normalCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'normalRelease')
    simulatorCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'simulatorRelease')
}
```

Library's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    publishNonDefault true

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        normal {
        }
        simulator {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

**Library:**

- split implementation between flavors by `productFlavors` (see my [sample project](https://github.com/igozhenko/gradle-27519128) if will have questions about that);
- add `publishNonDefault true` into its `build.gradle`

  From [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library)

  > It is also possible to publish all variants of a library. We are planning to allow this while using a normal project-to-project dependency (like shown above), but this is not possible right now due to limitations in Gradle (we are working toward fixing those as well).
  >   Publishing of all variants are not enabled by default.
  >   To enable them:
  >   
  >   android {
  >   publishNonDefault true
  >   }

**Application:**

- add `normal` and `simulator` product flavors (`productFlavors`);
- add next lines to `dependencies` section

  ```
  normalCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'normalRelease')
  simulatorCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'simulatorRelease')
  ```

  From [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library)

  > To create a dependency on another published artifact, you need to specify which one to use:
  >   
  >   dependencies {
  >   flavor1Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor1Release')
  >   flavor2Compile project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'flavor2Release')
  >   }

After all of that you'll be able to build 2 variants of applicaiton: normal and simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution for 2 libraries, it looks simpler. It's based on next from [official guide](https://github.com/igozhenko/gradle-27519128/tree/individual-libraries)

> Finally, like Build Types, Product Flavors can have their own dependencies. For instance, if the flavors are used to generate a ads-based app and a paid app, one of the flavors could have a dependency on an Ads SDK, while the other does not.
>   
>   dependencies {
>       flavor1Compile "..."
>   }

So you can create 2 individual libraries and create 2 flavors, for example, libraries are `library-normal` and `library-simulator` and flavors are `normal` and `simulator`.

Application `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tivogi.gradle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        normal {
        }
        simulator {
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    normalCompile project(":library-normal")
    simulatorCompile project(":library-simulator")
}
```

**Application:**

- add only those lines into `dependencies`;

  ```
  normalCompile project(":library-normal")
  simulatorCompile project(":library-simulator")
  ```

**Library:**

- does not require any change;

I published sample project of this solution at [individual-libraries](https://github.com/igozhenko/gradle-27519128/tree/individual-libraries) branch.